# Navigate to the URL without react-router - "_this.props.history is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to check authentity using tokens while loading the app and when user is not authorized navigate him to the log-in page. This method is inserted into Navbar component because it is on every page in the app, so it will be called any time. I tried to place the navbar component inside the Router but it doesn't work. The App.js with routing:

```
      <div className="App">
       <HomeNavbar history={this.props.history}/>
       <Router>
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
         <Route exact path="/addEvent" component={addEvent}/>
         <Route exact path="/register" component={RegisterPage}/>
         <Route exact path="/members" component={MembersList}/>
         <Route exact path="/event/:id" component={EventDetails}/>
         <Route exact path="/events" component={EventsList}/>
         <Route exact path="/user/:id" component={UserDetails}/>
         <Route path="/" component={EventsList}/>
       </Switch>
       </Router>
      </div>
```

As you can see HomeNavbar is outside the  but I want it that way because it displays on every page. How can I navigate to the other page from that component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to use the `withRouter` method from React Router. This will create a higher order component which receives all the router props. So instead of `HomeNavbar`, you'll have this:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

// create a new home navbar with router.
const HomeNavbarWithRouter = withRouter(HomeNavbar)

// after creating this, your HomeNavbar component will receive all the router props // such as `history, match, location`

// Finally, mount the HomeNavbarWithRouter instead:

<HomeNavbarWithRouter />
```

Comment: It doesn't work. When I place it the same it was I get "nvariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>". When I place it inside the Router I get "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState..."

Comment: Edit. It works. Thanks so much. I had to change a little bit the method in the HomeNavbar component

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class HomeNavbar extends React.Component {
    redner() { return (<div>Whatever should be here</div>); }
}

export default withRouter(HomeNavbar);
```

This will make history available in your component props.